# Roots of Equation

Tags: polynomials

Let the roots of the equation
$$
x^3 + px^2 + qx + r = 0
$$
be in arithmetic progression. Show that
$$
p^2 \ge 3q.
$$

Attempt: Let the roots be $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. Then
$$
\sum\alpha=-p, \quad \sum\alpha\beta=q, \quad\text{and}\quad \alpha\beta \gamma=-r.
$$
Since roots are in $AP$, we have $2\beta=\alpha+\gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

WLOG the roots are $a-d,a,a+d$

So, $-p=\cdots=3a$

and $q= a(a+d)+(a+d)(a-d)+(a-d)a=3a^2-d^2$

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the unknown $x$ by $-p/3$ to cancel the quadratic term and get a polynomial with $p'=0,q'=q-p^2/3$, while the roots still form an AP.

Then from $p'=0$, the roots must be $-t,0,t$, and by Vieta, $q'=-t^2/3<0$. This implies $q-p^3/3<0$.